# Mid 2015 Macbook Pro 15", Samsung 970 Evo 1TB SSD, Sintech Adapter, issues on boot

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, ssd, mojave

I recently updated my old Apple SSD to a Samsung 970 Evo 1TB, as I needed extra space for school and work. I also needed to run bootcamp, as I cannot run solidworks effectively through MacOS. Since I've installed the SSD, I've had quite a few problems with booting into either operating system (I run windows 10 through bootcamp), and looking up my problems hasn't revealed a solution, as most people are using a 960 Evo on High Sierra, from what I've seen.

I was curious as to whether or not there are certain steps I need to take to make sure the OS can recognize the NVME SSD as the boot drive every single time, as I get the blinking folder on boot from time to time. I've seen people say formatting as HFS+ as opposed to APFS will help, but I'd like your guys' opinions before I try anything else.

Comment: Mojave really doesn't like HFS+, it really wants you to be on APFS - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/327051/can-you-update-to-macos-10-14-mojave-without-converting-to-apfs

Comment: Have you disconnected and reconnected both the adapter and the SSD?  It could be a simple seating issue. When I upgraded my machine with the same gear, I remember having to use a lot of force to get the adapter all the way into the socket on the logic board.