# Can Mojave be installed on separate APFS volume under Catalina?

Tags: macos, mojave, catalina, apfs

I am running Catalina as my primary OS but am finding that I'd still like to run some 32-bit apps. Is it possible to create a new AFFS volume, install Mojave and simply run a dual-boot system?

**Things that did not work:**
I have created a new APFS volume, but I cannot figure how to make it bootable.

I was able to download an official build of Mojave but cannot get to the install screen because of an error message telling me `This copy of the “Install macOS” application is too old to be opened on this version of macOS.`

Comment: Put the installer on a USB key and boot from that - this will let you install to your new volume.  See [this](https://techmogulchannel.com/tutorial-how-to-downgrade-macos-mojave-to-older-macos-high-sierra-sierra-or-el-capitan/) and adjust names to `macOS\ Mojave.app` to make USB installer.

Comment: This Apple link [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) contains the command to make USB installer for Mojave : `sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Mojave.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume`

Comment: Warning: Yesterday, I rendered my Catalina unbootable - first updating Mojave with some security update (AFAIR 2019-001) and then updating Catalina to 10.15.1. Both systems were on external thumb drives. This may have been a coincidence though. But I suspect the two preboot partitions to cause a hickup of the 10.15.1 updater.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely possible. I just created this exact setup with macOS Catalina (10.15.1) as the "main" OS, and a separate macOS Mojave (10.14.6) installation in an APFS Volume (same disk, same container).

Follow these steps:

## Step 1

**Download "Install macOS Mojave" archive**

1. Click on [this link](https://apps.apple.com/gb/app/macos-mojave/id1398502828) which will open the Mac App Store on the Mojave page.
2. Click Get.
3. The Software Update window up from System Preferences will open showing the latest version of Mojave. Confirm that you want to download the software, you'll also see a warning that you are downloading an older version of the OS, ignore it.
4. Wait while the macOS downloads - it may take a while.
5. Once it’s downloaded DO NOT click on Open - you don't want to install it yet.

(from https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/downgrade-macos-3581872/)

## Step 2

**Create APFS volume**

1. Open "Disk Utility"
2. Click "View" -> "Show All Devices" (<kbd>⌘2</kbd>)
3. Click on "Container disk1" and "Add APFS Volume..."
4. Enter `Mojave` in "Name" (leave "Format" as "APFS" - I also did not specify any size options)

## Step 3

**Create bootable installation media for Mojave**

Follow the official instructions at [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372)

In short summarized form:

Format a min 16GB USB stick using Mac OS Extended, call it `boot`, then run:

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Mojave.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/boot
```

Replace `/Applications` with `~/Downloads` in case the installer is still in your Downloads folder.

## Step 4

**Boot from install media, and install to `Mojave` volume**

1. Reboot your computer, hold down the Option key (<kbd>⌥</kbd>) **before** the Apple logo appears
2. Choose the USB media (Mojave installer)
3. Click "Reinstall macOS" once the "macOS Utilities" screen appears
4. Select the `Mojave` volume when asked where to install

Once the installation is finished, you can use the "Startup Disk" program to set you main Catalina installation as the default. When you want to boot Mojave, just restart the computer, hold <kbd>⌥</kbd>, and select "Mojave".

Comment: Is it possible without separate installation media? I don't have a big enough USB stick.

Comment: I'm trying this, however in step 1 when I click "Get" in the App Store, it says "the requested version of macOS is not available". I have Catalina and wish to download the full Mojave installer to create a virtual machine (NOT to install it on my main OS).
Is there perhaps a direct download link somewhere for the full Mojave installer?

Comment: @tbodt - see my answer here https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/390737/333666

Comment: The problem I hit on MBP 16 is that at step 4 the Reinstalll launches Catalina installer ...

Answer (score 4):

Someone asked in a comment here if macOS can be installed without first creating a separate installation media / usb boot disk.

Yes you can, provided your macOS installer is not in the same volume where you want to install macOS too.

Here's how:

1. Let's assume you have two hard disks or partitions named *Catalina* and *Mojave* respectively.
2. You have macOS Catalina on */Volume/Catalina*.
3. You have downloaded and copied the macOS Mojave installer into a directory called 'OS' and hence the installer is at */Volume/Catalina/OS*.
4. Using Disk Utility, you have formatted */Volume/Mojave* as either HFS+ (best for older hard disks) or APFS (recommended if you have a SSD drive).
5. Now boot into macOS Recovery mode - press the <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> keys when switching on your Mac and don't let go till you see the Apple logo
6. In recovery, open the Terminal and run this command:
   `$ /Volume/Catalina/OS/Install\ macOS\ Mojave.app/Contents/Resources/startosinstall --volume /Volume/Mojave`
   *(note that the `$` is not part of the command. It is the prompt shown in terminal where you type the command)*.

**Note**: If you have disabled SIP, you can run the command without booting into recovery (see the comments for more details).

Comment: `—volume` is only available as a parameter in recovery mode, not normal boot mode. Is it possible to run `startosinstall` to a specific volume in normal boot mode?

Comment: @ZakTaccardi Interesting - yes, you are right. According to this answer - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/336846 - the --volume option can only be used in normal boot mode when SIP is disabled. But unless you have already disabled it, you will need to go to the recovery to do so, in which case you might as well just start the installation from there.

Answer (score 2):

Apple has moved the old MacOS installers around since this article was published.  I found the answer on appleinsider here: 
https://appleinsider.com/articles/19/11/23/how-to-get-an-old-macos-installer-from-apple

The article also provides links to earlier versions as well.

The link to get Mojave is:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macos-mojave/id1398502828?ls=1&mt=12

Comment: Thanks for updating. An edit to:the accepted answer is also a perfect way to keep that post current.

Comment: Thanks @bmike it's my first post and I hadn't realised this.  Will do so in future

Comment: Pretty good post - thanks for being here!