# trying to install mojave on another volume

Tags: terminal, mojave, partition, install

i was following the instructions in the bottom part of this question:

[Can Mojave be installed on separate APFS volume under Catalina?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/374846/)

I’ve created a partitioned separate volume (named portal) and followed all the steps, but when I put in the command in terminal in recovery mode

`$ /volume/mac/users/bluelina/portaling/Install\ macOS\ Mojave.app/Contents/Resources/startosinstall --volume /Volume/portal`

it says command not found

i could not find a way to put the mojave installer directly under /mac/ hence the longer code. i’ve tried deleting .app from behind mojave because the name of the file is just mojave. it’s the file i downloaded from the app store, it says it’s an ‘alias’ so i’m hoping that’s the right kind of file

i’m just trying to get an older OS so I can play portal again, if that was unclear from how i named the directories

UPDATE:

```
diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         200.7 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         50.1 GB    disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +50.1 GB    disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s3
   1:                APFS Volume portal                  835.6 KB   disk1s1

/dev/disk2 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +200.7 GB   disk2
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Mac - Data              157.7 GB   disk2s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 81.7 MB    disk2s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                528.9 MB   disk2s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk2s4
   5:                APFS Volume Mac                     11.3 GB    disk2s5

/dev/disk3 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk3
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk3s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Matthias                999.9 GB   disk3s2
```

Comment: Your command line seems bad. Try with  `sudo /Volumes/mac/users/bluelina/portaling/Install\ macOS\ Mojave.app/Contents/Resources/startosinstall --volume /Volumes/portal`

Comment: great now it says no such file or directory  and having either ‘sudo’ or ‘$’ in front results in a ‘command not found’ message. guess i gotta see if i can try to put the folder directly under the mac directory

Comment: Can you add the results of `diskutil list` in your question?

Comment: @AlinaG The `$` is not part of the command. It is to indicate the *prompt* where the command should be typed. Type the command without the `$` in the beginning. And `sudo` is not required in Recovery as you already have *root* privileges there.